# Can the four-f correlator be solved geometrically?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

For an optics lab my class created a four-f correlator and saw how a lens can create a Fourier transform of an image, and we can filter out spatial frequencies of an image by blocking parts of the Fourier plane. I am wondering if there is a way to derive this besides using a Fourier transform. Can this operation be done by a purely geometric approach, by measuring angles and such?

Comment: I believe the core operating principle is Fresnel diffraction, which is not a part of geometric optics, so I doubt it.

Comment: You can make the four-f correlator still create an image in a far-field setting, so Fraunhofer diffraction is still relevant, I would think. Unless the spatial filter is in the Fresnel zone, in which case I might be wrong about that.